# EMMC doesn't get recognized as a storage device in windows

Tags: windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suLLp.png)I bought this EMMC from MKS pi in order to flash the armbian in the MKS pi board. The problem is, I connect the EMMC with adapter in the USB hub, It appear for less than 1 second and than it disappears. I need to format this EMMC disk to flash the makerbase armbian sistem on it.

Anyone knows how can I fix this?

[image: example]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management, too. Are you sure your SD card reader is compatible?

Comment: inserted the image of disk managemente already

Comment: Instead of a generic USB-to-SD_card adapter, you probably need to use a USB adapter that explicitly supports eMMC such as https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805428404625.html?pdp_npi=2%40dis%21USD%21%246.99%21%241.99%21%21%21%21%21%402103010b16889521659285068edf15%2112000033755356288%21btf&_t=pvid%3A0ebe0ee3-e69c-4aa6-b1cf-ceea1dd0f518&afTraceInfo=1005005614719377__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1688952166&spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.mainProduct&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not conflate eMMC and SD card.**
They are similar and share some commonality in their interfaces, but they are distinct. The similarities do allow a combined MMC+SD controller as found in several SoCs, but the driver is expected to identify the actual medium in use, and then configure the controller mode and use the appropriate SD or MMC commands.

If your computer (or USB adapter) only has an SD card interface (rather than a combined MMC+SD), then such a controller may be able to detect that there is a "card", but will be unable to read or write any data to the eMMC module.

Instead of a generic USB-to-SD_card adapter, you probably need to use a USB adapter that explicitly supports the eMMC module you have such as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By EMMC, they mean SDcard. Yes it uses eMMC, but it is part of an SDcard which is the object.

It is an SDCard, USB mass storage, (it contains MMC, but it is ca SDCard), like a USB stick is, then you would first need to make a filesystem and partition, for Windows Explorer to show it (counter-intuitive, but that's how volumes work).

*If you want to see it in Explorer, you will need to initialise it in disk management (search start menu), then create a simple volume on the device. You don't need to do this to flash the OS.*

If there is no window about initialising the disk, right click on the Free Space of the disk, and create a new volume for Windows to show it (it will not show a blank disk).

If you are flashing the drive (installing an operating system), just use a program to flash it (i.e. Raspberry Imager, or Etcher). It should show up in there.

*On other computer boards, it may or may not be compatible with Raspberry Pi images. If not compatible, or the image is corrupt, it will not run.*

If it was actually a bare eMMC chip (integrated circuit), then this is not the normal way to format it (for a single board computer, or microcontroller, you would usually flash a an on-board chip, using the data port. Or otherwise using a flash storage writer.

Comment: https://www.hta3d.com/en/mks-emmc-8g-module-and-adapter-for-mks-skipr-and-mks-pi-boards

Thanks for the reply, very elucidative. This is the eMMC I mean, I need to flash it in windows. The manufacturer say it should behave like a mass storage device, but it isn't showing up in my computer window.

I tried to open it in disk manager, but there I can only change it letter name, not format it.

Comment: @LeonardoG.Pate Yes, SDcards are a normal mass storage device. Windows doesn't show blank storage devices in File Explorer. You will first need to create a volume in Disk Management, for it to show in Explorer (right click on the Free Space and select Simple Volume).

But you don't need to do this to use Raspberry Pi Imager, or Etcher.